# Why does my DJS role claim message work for a few hours, but suddenly stops?

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

I created a DJS Discord Bot hosted on Heroku that seems to work perfectly fine, except for the role claim command that I created. It works completely fine, the bot reacts with the message in the channel, and gives users roles that they react with. However, after a few hours, it just stops working. I am receiving no errors.

Since the code seems to be working fine, I thought that this might have something to do with my Heroku application, maybe it was falling asleep and that is what's affecting it. But verified my account and it now has plenty of free dyno hours, and this is still happening.

I have absolutely no clue what to do now... I've never seen this happen to anyone else and I don't know what's causing it.

```js
if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
if (user.bot) return;
if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
    if (reaction.emoji.id === '842102278223167528') {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(technologyRole);
    } else if (reaction.emoji.id === '871172469334089738') {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(engineeringRole);
    } else if (reaction.emoji.id === '871172735114555393') {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(roboticsRole);     
    } else if (reaction.emoji.id === '870823307467968603') {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(mathRole);  
    } else if (reaction.emoji.id === '871172490892804107') {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(chemistryRole);
    } else if (reaction.emoji.id === '870823212441800714') {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(biomedRole);
    } else if (reaction.emoji.id === '842102248993718374') {
        await
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code into your question (not an external site). Also, trim it down for it to have only the relevant parts (only things related to this question)

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is when the server is restarted and your bot also, is not listening to the message events since you made it that it listens to the message that is created by writing the command. The roughest solution would be to let the bot write command in some testing channel that only mods can see once he is started.
For example:

```
bot.once('ready', () => {   
    console.log('DiscordBot is online!');
    bot.channels.cache.get("testing channelid")
        .send("-reactionrole");  //Or whatever the command is to make the message your member are supposed to react to                                        
});
```

So you probably have bot.once ready event made already, just add the two extra lines, let me know if it helped!